# Variable importance order in GLM/logistic regression

Tags: r, classification, logistic-regression, h2o, glm

My data frame has 100 rows. I try to build binary generalized linear model:

```
model = h2o.glm(family="binomial", x=predictors, y=response,
                training_frame=training_df, 
                missing_values_handling="Skip",
                lambda=0, compute_p_values = TRUE, nfolds = 7)
var_imp = h2o.varimp(model)
```

**Model #1** (AUC= 0.826 ± 0.012) has the following variable importance order:

```
                    variable relative_importance scaled_importance
1                          Y           1.7976670         1.0000000
2                          C           1.3799875         0.7676547
3                        AGE           0.8155962         0.4536971
4                    V_4_sum           0.6452078         0.3589140
5                         T2           0.3446666         0.1917300
6                    V_3_sum           0.2452110         0.1364051
7                         T1           0.2028320         0.1128307
```

After some time I added new variable *G* and **model #2** (AUC= 0.943 ± 0.015) performance improved significantly (as I expected):

```
                    variable relative_importance scaled_importance
1                          G          8.25206428        1.00000000
2                          C          2.23826129        0.27123653
3                    V_4_sum          1.14390917        0.13862097
4                         T1          0.82906448        0.10046753
5                    V_3_sum          0.76380841        0.09255968
6                         T2          0.20089827        0.02434521
7                        AGE          0.19790613        0.02398262
8                          Y          0.09374866        0.01136063
```

As you can see variable importance order has changed. *G* is now the most important var, but *Y* is at the end (previously it was the first).
*AGE* rank has decreased in the new model too.

Is such effect well known property of h2o *varimp* function for GLM (logistic regression for binary classification)? Can I say something general about *AGE* or *Y* importance using *varimp* order?

What alternative methods can be applied to generate variable importance order in my case? I would like to have more stable order of the top variables.

Comment: You should check your predictors are not heavily correlated. It could be that G leads us to the same information as Age and Y. As an example, in under 18s, you might find that age and diet explain risk of heart problems. Adding weight may reduce the importance of both, since often the two would be closely linked.

Comment: There is 0.80 correlation only in *0_* class for Y and C, and no strong correlations with G or AGE in any class.

Comment: Could you share the output of `dput(training_df)` ?

Comment: This is my data frame: https://box.psnc.pl/f/c0f7fb67a8/?raw=1